# Altium Variant Problem

Tags: schematics, altium

I have variants in schematic sheet. You can see the enclosed picture. But when I right click on the Project -> Variants there are no variants over there. But I can see the schematic sheet.

How can I delete all variants on my project? Why this problem happened?

Comment: Can you see any variants listed in your project panel ?

Comment: Have you tried recompiling your project and/or reseting any DRC errors etc. ?

Comment: Otherwise have you tried contacting Altium technical support or the on-line forum ? The online forum is generally free of charge ...

Comment: @citizen I can't see any variants in my project panel. It seems there is no variant in project panel. I tried recompiling the project and I get same errors.

Comment: @citizen Just a note that in English there is no space before the question mark.

Comment: @JYelton do you consider that a grammatical error or a lexical abberation ;-)

Comment: @citizen Unsure. But when text wraps at different zooms or screen widths, the question marks can be separated from the sentence they belong to, which leads to unclear formatting. I believe in French a non-breaking space character is used (or something) to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @JYelton yes I agree that it "... leads to unclear formatting" however when I hand write in english I do leave a space beteen ... One could also argue that having an exclamation mark next to a word that terminates with "l" could be misread as a word terminating with "ll" and that could lead to a perceived spelling mistake, in any text written with the Ariel font ;-)

Comment: @citizen That has more to do with font rendering and kerning. I'm just trying to offer advice as a technical editor.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows the Compile Views tab.

Compile views are generated for each instance of a sheet.  In a flat design, the compile view will take the name of the file itself.  In a hierarchical design, they are named by the sheet symbol.  It appears you have two instances named "21" and "22" in this design.  These might be separate sheet symbols, named as such, or created by a REPEAT() multichannel sheet symbol and auto-named according to project settings.

Comment: but there is only 20 schematics in my project. I don't have 21 and 22 schematic sheets. I imported from another project to Altium. It that effects?

Comment: In that case you should just create a new project and then right-click "Add Existing to Project"and add all the relevant schematics to your project from scratch. Then arrange your variants as required ...